# How to kill already in use port in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, port, kill

**It shows this error**

error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081.
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081

**Things i have tried**

kill -9, killall node, adb reconnect etc nothing works it again shows same error when **npm start**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   Im using Linux Try This !
```

```html
    find which PID is using ur Port{8081} by following command
    sudo lsof -i :8081

    Output something like this:
     COMMAND  PID     USER     FD    TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
              node    7689   kishan   23u  IPv6  65425      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)
              
    then fire this command to kill server 

    syntax:- kill -9 USER

    eg:
    kill -9 7689
```

Comment: I tried to find on which port it is running.
Output is:-
`$ netstat -ano | findstr :8081
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7056
  TCP    [::]:8081              [::]:0                 LISTENING       7056`

After that I tried kill-9 8081 and it says no such process

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-kill-server-when-seeing-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-16c4c4d7fe5d

Comment: visit this page there you find way for windows easily

Comment: thats Great! keep Going Dude...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in terminal

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: Still shows the same error "listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081"

Comment: Restart the PC. Might fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8081)
```

It works for me

Comment: I'm using window system, i guess lsof is for the linux